# Can't click on Guide/Tip boxes in Careers

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

In careers, when you click inside a text input box, you will often see a popup appear to the right. It'll give you some tips as to what to do, what to say, etc etc.

[image]

As I pondered a personal statement earlier, I moused over the popup. My cursor changed to signify that I was hovering over text that I could interact with. However, when I attempted to highlight some text (for no particular reason), **the popup disappeared**.

While yes, it's not incredibly important, it appears that you can interact with the element, and then it disappears when you try. I would say the box should not disappear when clicked on, but should provide a small x in the corner to close it.

I wasn't sure whether to mark this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), feel free to re-tag.

<sub>Chrome 18.0.1025.168</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The help box appears when you're typing in the text box.  If you move your focus outside, the help box disappears.  Hence, clicking the popup makes the help box disappear.

Since there's not really any good reason to need to interact with the help box, I don't see this is as a meaningful bug.

Comment: That's fine. What I'd in that case is for the text to not think it's selectable. From a usability standpoint, I don't want my cursor to change to a selection cursor, because I can't select.